# Is it possible to generate generate thiessen (Voronoï) polygons using the SQL Server Spatial datatypes?

Tags: sql-server, spatial-index

I have a bunch of points in a SQL Server database using the `geography` data type, that I would like to be able to generate thiessen polygons for.

Is this processing available natively within SQL Server, or must this processing be done outside of the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there's no built-in method to do this, but it can certainly be done using CLR-integration. I borrowed the [Pro Spatial with SQL Server 2012](http://www.apress.com/9781430234913) book from a library some time ago and I remember that it included an example of how to do Voronoi tessellations in Chapter 15, and the sample code too for it is available online for the curious to look at.